# Execute a job on 5th Working Day of month

Tags: c#, quartz.net, quartz.net-3.0

I am using Quartz.net to schedule my jobs. I need to run a few jobs based on nth working day of a month. E.g., 5th Working Day of every month. So, if 1st of the month is a Tuesday, the schedule should run on the following Monday.

The Java version of Quartz does seem to have something similar, but can't see this in Quartz.NET.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/cookbook/FifthWorkingDayTrigger

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
R

Comment: I would have a task that runs everyday, that checks if TheDayIsMagical() and aborts on false.